# Applying Excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I do not know excel at very advanced level. So asking a doubt.

There is data in column Z and AA. I want to enter day name, so that I can get who are on weekly off on that day.

I am unable to do.

[image]

Comment: I can give you the answer but I would like you to try it first. Read up on [FILTER](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759) function. ;)

Comment: I applied this formula:

=XLOOKUP(AD8,AA9:AA17,Z9:Z17,"",0,-1)

But I can only retain 1 value whereas, 2 DE are on weekly off on particular day. So how to retain 2 values.

Comment: Try with FILTER. it is much simpler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER($Z$4:$Z$12,$AA$4:$AA$12=$AE$3))
```

[image]

Comment: Not sure why you applied the UNIQUE on the result